# Resistance seen by capacitor

Tags: transistors, mosfet, resistance

[image]
I'm trying to find the resistance seen by capacitor \$C_1\$, but I'm not getting the correct solution. In order to make the problem simpler, I say that \$R_{C_1}=R_{P_1}||(R_{down})\$.   I start off by grounding all voltage sources. This means that \$R_{P_1}=r_{p1}\$.
For the NMOS transistor, since \$V_{GS_N}=0 \Rightarrow \$ the resistance from \$V_{out}\$ down to ground will be \$r_{n_1}\$. For the transistor \$P_2, V_{SG_{p2}}\neq0\$, thus we have \$r_{p_2}||\left(\frac{1}{G_{M_{p2}}}\right)\$, where \$G_{M_{p2}}=(g_{m_{p2}}+g_{mb_{p2}})\$
In total, that would mean
$$R_{down}=r_{p_2}||\left(\frac{1}{G_{M_{p2}}}\right)+r_{n_1}=r_{n_1}+\frac{r_{p_2}}{1+r_{p_2}(G_{M_{p2}})}$$
However, according to the solutions \$R_{down}=\frac{r_{n_1}+r_{p_2}}{1+r_{p_2}(G_{M_{p2}})}\$
I've tried redrawing this in all possible ways, but I can't think of how I could end up with the same result as the solutions. What could I be doing wrong?